# Snapping options with Move Feature in QGIS3

Tags: qgis-3, snapping, move

Is it possible to snap (i.e. precisely align) features when using the 'move feature' tool in QGIS3? I understand that you couldn't in earlier versions but wondered whether it was possible now.

Someone suggested a workaround for previous versions that involved using the vertex tool to move the feature but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, enable snapping. [image]

To show this tool go to view -> toolbars:

[image]

[image]